# Dynamically loading exe file

Tags: windows, delphi, dll, delphi-7

I'm trying to dynamically load an exe file from my program and run SomeProcedure from that dynamicaly loaded exe. Here's what I'm doing in loaded exe - library.exe

```
interface    

procedure SomeProcedure; stdcall;

implementation    

procedure SomeProcedure;
begin
  ShowMessage('Ala has a cat');
end;
```

And here's my exe that load's library.exe and try to run SomeProcedure from it.

```
type
  THandle = Integer;
  TProc = procedure();

var
  AHandle: THandle;
  Proc: TProc;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AHandle := LoadLibrary('library.exe');
  if AHandle <> 0 then begin
    @Proc := GetProcAddress(AHandle, 'SomeProcedure');
    if @Proc <> nil then 
      try    
        Proc;
      finally
        FreeLibrary(AHandle);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Unfortunately it's not working - AHandle has an address but GetProcAddress always returns nil. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a `exports SomeProcedure;` in your project file?

Comment: AAMOF I have no idea what does the `export` directive do...

Comment: @Sertac: IIRC, it is ignored. It used to have a meaning a long time ago.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Added `exports SomeProcedure`, now I have an AV in call to Proc. And then `floating point stack check at 0x000000`

Comment: @Just - You're missing the `stdcall` in your `TProc` definition, but I'm not sure if it would make a difference.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz It's not making any difference :(

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz, just FYI: `export` directive is a 16-bit thing, makes subroutine `far` and generates prologue and epilogue code.

Comment: @OnTheFly - that is the export directive for procedures and functions, exports (with an s) in the dpr tells the compiler what functions to export in a library project. Not sure what it will do in a standard exe. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Procedures_and_Functions and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Writing_Dynamically_Loaded_Libraries

Comment: @Gerry The exports directive does just the same in an exe as in a dll

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan - I assumed as much as it allows `exports SomeFunct` from within a "program" dpr as well as a "library" dll, but I didn't have time to figure out what the result would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the very best of my knowledge, what you are attempting is not possible. You cannot use LoadLibrary to load a .exe file, and then call its exported functions. You can only have one .exe file loaded into a process. You'll need to move the functionality into a library, or a COM server, or some other solution.

As Sertac points out, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms684175.aspx) does cover this:

> LoadLibrary can also be used to load other executable modules. For example, the function can specify an .exe file
>   to get a handle that can be used in FindResource or LoadResource. However, do not use LoadLibrary to run an .exe file. Instead, use the CreateProcess function.

You can use GetProcAddress with the module handle of an executable. But you have to obtain the module handle by calling GetModuleHandle(0), for example.

Comment: This answer is of course correct, even hinted to some extent in the documentation for `LoadLibrary`: *"..do not use LoadLibrary to run an .exe file.."*. I gave up trying to understand the mechanism it fails; either the IAT is messed up or pointers passed even in module boundary point to nowhere. Simple fact is the loader does not help with this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

As David already pointed out it is nearly impossible. Well not impossible I would say. Just for the sake of understanding you could teoretically call CreateProcess and then hook its call and the calls that follow. One of the calls is also [ZwCreateSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I played with things like that a long time ago and it is theoretically possible to do it. CreateProcess creates an empty process context that then gets filled with other Zw/Nt kernell calls. Knowing the calls you could supply the content.

But that was theory and even that is hacking into the OS. As David pointed out it is impossible to do it in a sane and documented way. What you can do hovewer is extract the exe as a resource to a temporary file and the execute it. You can then wait for it to end and after that delete the file. That is the only way to do it. To do it all in RAM is a no go.

EDIT:

Here is an article on a [technique](http://www.security.org.sg/code/loadexe.html) that can be used. But its an ugly hack :)

Answer (score -1):

"now I have an AV in call to Proc" - you forget to define "stdcall" in definition of TProc.

Just created small sample demonstrating loading/executing of exported function from another EXE.

Application 1:

```
program Exe4Export;
uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit3 in 'Unit3.pas' {Form3},
  ExportTypes in 'ExportTypes.pas';

{$R *.res}

function Test:integer; stdcall; export;
begin
  result := 7;
end;

exports
  Test;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm3, Form3);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Application 2:

```
type
  TExtProc = function: integer; stdcall;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  h: HMODULE;
  p: TExtProc;
begin
  h := LoadLibrary('Exe4Export.exe');
  p := GetProcAddress(h, 'Test');
  if assigned(p) then
    caption := IntToStr(p);
  FreeLibrary(h);
end;
```

So app2 loads app1 into own address space (yes, it is possible for DLL), then get address of function and call it in same way like for DLL.

Comment: Your example works because the exe file does nothing. As soon as you try to do anything, it will fall over.

Comment: 2Sertac Akyuz: "string" is bad idea because it is managed object and it is tricky (for DLL too). PChar is just pointer, we load EXE in same adress space as calling process, so it will be ok to use PChar (for DLL too).

Comment: 2David Heffernan: Examle is just example. It is supposed to show that it is possible to load EXE in the same way as DLL and call procedures from that EXE. And example does it. It was the asked question, isn't it ? What you can do in EXE loaded this way - it depends (for DLL too). Maybe you can suggest some example to demonstrate disadvantages of EXE ? I guess many system function we use with Win API actually implemented in system EXEs.

Comment: @Andrei - Well, that's why I offered the pchar alternative. Have tried it? You'll receive garbage if you don't have some kind of luck with the image base of the loaded executable. Just try it.

Comment: 2Sertac Akyuz: You was right, it doesn't return correct pointer for PChar (just tried to return pointer to global string), not sure why. Will check it bit later.

Comment: It returns garbage because what you are trying to do is not supported. You'd need to write your own loader. Good luck with that. Much easier just to put the code in a library as nature intended.

Comment: Use the @ sign to ensure people are notified

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: Seems that you was right. There is no way to use exported functions in EXE from another process (at least there is no way to implement it in reasonable time with guarantied result).