# LoadLibrary fails with error code 193

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, loadlibrary

I'm stuck as to why I can't load my dll "interfac" using LoadLibrary. It seems to be failing when loading a dependency but I'm not sure why.

Here's the code:

```
AfxMessageBox(L"before load library");
HMODULE interfacDll = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\QA\\Pcdlrn\\Win32\\Release\\INTERFAC.DLL"));
if (!interfacDll)
  DWORD dw = GetLastError(); // returns 0xc1 (193)
AfxMessageBox(L"after load library");
```

And here's the output from gflags (x86)'s loader snaps:

```
18a0:2a40 @ 06858973 - LdrGetDllHandleEx - ENTER: DLL name: ntdll.dll DLL path: NULL
18a0:2a40 @ 06858973 - LdrGetDllHandleEx - INFO: Locating DLL ntdll.dll in path C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpFindLoadedDll - ENTER: DLL name: ntdll.dll DLL path: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpFindLoadedDll - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrGetDllHandleEx - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrGetProcedureAddressEx - INFO: Locating procedure "KiUserExceptionDispatcher" by name
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrLoadDll - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL DLL path: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\syste
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpLoadDll - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL DLL path: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\syst
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpLoadDll - INFO: Loading DLL C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL from path C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\sys
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL DLL path: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpSearchPath - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL DLL path: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\s
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpResolveFileName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpResolveFileName - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpResolveDllName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpResolveDllName - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpSearchPath - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06859036 - LdrpMapViewOfSection - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL
'CNCServer.exe': Loaded 'C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.dll', Symbols loaded.
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpMapViewOfSection - RETURN: Status: 0x40000003
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpRelocateImage - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpProtectAndRelocateImage - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpRelocateImage - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpHandleOneOldFormatImportDescriptor - INFO: DLL "C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL" imports "PCDLRN.exe"
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpLoadImportModule - ENTER: DLL name: PCDLRN.exe DLL path: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\W
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - ENTER: DLL name: PCDLRN.exe DLL path: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windo
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpFindKnownDll - ENTER: DLL name: PCDLRN.exe
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpFindKnownDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpSearchPath - ENTER: DLL name: PCDLRN.exe DLL path: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveFileName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release\PCDLRN.exe
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveFileName - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveFileName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Windows\system32\PCDLRN.exe
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveFileName - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveFileName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Windows\system\PCDLRN.exe
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveFileName - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveFileName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Windows\PCDLRN.exe
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveFileName - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveFileName - ENTER: DLL name: .\PCDLRN.exe
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveFileName - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveDllName - ENTER: DLL name: .\PCDLRN.exe
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpResolveDllName - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpSearchPath - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpMapViewOfSection - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\PCDLRN.exe
'CNCServer.exe': Loaded 'C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\PCDLRN.exe', Symbols loaded.
18a0:2a40 @ 06859597 - LdrpMapViewOfSection - RETURN: Status: 0x40000003
'CNCServer.exe': Unloaded 'C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\PCDLRN.exe'
18a0:2a40 @ 06859597 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc000007b
18a0:2a40 @ 06859597 - LdrpLoadImportModule - ERROR: Loading DLL PCDLRN.exe from path C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:
18a0:2a40 @ 06859597 - LdrpLoadImportModule - RETURN: Status: 0xc000007b
18a0:2a40 @ 06859597 - LdrpHandleOneOldFormatImportDescriptor - ERROR: Loading "?????" from the import table of DLL "C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL" failed with status 0xc000007b
18a0:2a40 @ 06859613 - LdrpUnloadDll - INFO: Unmapping DLL "C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL"
'CNCServer.exe': Unloaded 'C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.dll'
18a0:2a40 @ 06859613 - LdrpLoadDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc000007b
18a0:2a40 @ 06859613 - LdrLoadDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc000007b
```

I should mention that I am using 64-bit windows but all my executable code is either targeted to x86 (c#) or win32 (c++).

How do I resolve this issue?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

p.s. Here's the dependency walker output:
[image: INTERFAC.dll]

p.p.s. here's a screenshot showing that my DLLs are x86:

[image: x86]

p.p.p.s. here's the linker inputs for interfac.dll:

[image: linker inputs]

Edit. Here's the output of dumpbin:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file pcdlrn.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

Section contains the following exports for PCDLRN.exe

00000000 characteristics
5796AD2A time date stamp Mon Jul 25 20:22:02 2016
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
    5784 number of functions
    5784 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

     1    0 0029CDF0 ??0?$CArray@V?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@V12@@@QAE@XZ = ??0?$CArray@V?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@V12@@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall CArray<class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > >::CArray<class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > >(void))
...
5783 1696 02593550 ?zoomOutFine@VisionTargetControls@UIEvents@@YAXXZ = ?zoomOutFine@VisionTargetControls@UIEvents@@YAXXZ (void __cdecl UIEvents::VisionTargetControls::zoomOutFine(void))
5784 1697 02593640 ?zoomOutMaximum@VisionTargetControls@UIEvents@@YAXXZ = ?zoomOutMaximum@VisionTargetControls@UIEvents@@YAXXZ (void __cdecl UIEvents::VisionTargetControls::zoomOutMaximum(void))

Summary

  2C0000 .data
    1000 .fnp_dir
    1000 .fnp_mar
  AFA000 .rdata
   1B000 .rsrc
 2E7A000 .text
   E5000 .textidx
    1000 .tls
```

Comment: It's meaningless to call `GetLastError()` like that. Check `GetLastError()` only if the function fails.

Comment: [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) does not return an `HINSTANCE`, and you're not checking to see if it fails or not before calling GetLastError. You can only use GetLastError if two conditions are met first: 1) The function has to specifically say in the documentation that you can retrieve error details using GetLastError, and 2) the function has to actually fail, or there is no relevant or meaningful information for GetLastError to return.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Correct. This was sample code to reproduce the problem. I've updated the code for clarity.

Comment: Error 193 is ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT, most likely meaning the file is corrupted, or it's a 32-bit DLL you're loading into a 64-bit process or vice versa.

Comment: @markf78 _"This was sample code to reproduce the problem."_ Far off from a [MCVE] as required here.

Comment: `INFO: DLL "C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL" imports "PCDLRN.exe"` That looks odd. Could you post the `.def` file, the `.vcxproj` file, the `makefile`, or whatever is that brings in that dependency?

Comment: @immibis the bitness appears to be OK if I am interpreting the dependency walker output correctly. Please see attachment.

Comment: See also [Windows Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx). The error means *"%1 is not a valid Win32 application"* It looks like 32bit calling 64bit problem.

Comment: Dependency walker even displays error source: **Error: Modules with different CPU types were found**

Comment: @markf78 Your Dependency Walker image doesn't show **your** DLL in the details window.  You need to scroll down and check the CPU column for **your** DLL.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie See atttachment.

Comment: @Ari0nhh It's because I was using the x64 dependency walker. i've updated the first image to be output from x86 dependency walker.

Comment: @markf78 You haven't answered my question about `PCDLRN.exe` yet. A `DLL` that's statically linked to the import library of an `EXE` will cause the same `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` when `LoadLibrary`'d. If you look at the loader snaps, the module that actually triggers the error is `PCDLRN.exe`.

Comment: @dxiv I think you're onto something here. I've attached the linker inputs for INTERFAC.dll.

Comment: @markf78 That answers *how* the `.exe` got linked in as a dependency. For the *why* part try removing `pcdlrn.lib` from the linker inputs, and see what happens. I don't see any good reason why it would (have needed to) be there to begin with.

Comment: @KenWhite: *"LoadLibrary does not return an `HINSTANCE`"* - Well, yes. But that doesn't matter ([What is the difference between HINSTANCE and HMODULE?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903)). And your preconditions for calling `GetLastError` are wrong. An API does not necessarily have to fail for `GetLastError` to return meaningful information (see [CreateMutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411.aspx), for example).

Comment: @IInspectable: It makes it quite clear the poster didn't read the documentation. It also helped make my point about reading the documentation. I'm well aware that the *current implementation* makes HINSTANCE and  HMODULE the same thing, but for clarity it's wrong to confuse them, and in this case the poster used HRESULT, which is a COM return value type. Sloppily written code that misuses types can make bugs harder to figure out or lead to more errors. If you didn't catch the HRESULT being totally out of place, you've picked the wrong user name here.

Comment: (continued) You're right, though. GetLastError sometimes has a use when there isn't actually a failure. But unless it's **documented** as being useful otherwise, the *must fail* rule is true. CreateMutex does indeed *document* an exception to that rule. Read #1 in the comment you responded to, which mentions the documentation. In *no* case that I'm aware of is *Call GetLastError at will, whether a function fails or succeeds, and especially when you've not even checked the function's return value, and you can rely on the GetLastError result to have meaning*.

Comment: @KenWhite: I agree, that writing clean code is a Good Thing™, and using the correct type with respect to semantics should always be favored. Your comment made it sound like there was a technical issue when declaring an `HINSTANCE` in place of `HMODULE`. Your general advice on when to call `GetLastError` is still wrong. And I didn't find any mention of `HRESULT`s either, neither in the current question nor in its history. What did I miss?

Comment: @IInspectable: My memory failed me. I thought I remembered the initial version of the post containing HRESULT, which was then quickly changed to HINSTANCE. It was getting late here when I posted my first comment; I should have reviewed better before replying to you. So you didn't miss it. My fault. :-(

Comment: And my general advice on when to call GetLastError is not *wrong*, at least not in the first part. You should **never** rely on GetLastError having meaning without first reviewing the docs for the function you're calling. You're right that the second rule should have mentioned the exceptions about functions documented to use it during certain conditions when the function succeeds, but again you don't know that's the case until you've read  the documentation first.

Comment: @dxiv Unfortunately, the pcdlrn.exe and the interfac.dll code is extremely tightly coupled. It's a legacy code base and I am unable to modify it in the near-term (another group controls this code). FYI The LoadLibrary code snippet is from my executable cncserver.exe.

Comment: @markf78 That simply won't work, for the same reasons discussed at [Dynamically loading exe file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218593/dynamically-loading-exe-file).

Comment: @dxiv really LoadLibrary can with no error load exe file too. but if PE have no IMAGE_FILE_DLL flag (so this is exe,not dll) loader not process import from this PE. so must not be error while loading PCDLRN.exe , but if PCDLRN.exe call any imported api - will be crash, because import not binded

Comment: @RbMm LoadLibrary is documented to be able to load EXEs, but it cannot bind them, so they are useless except for LoadResource or similar. Besides, most EXEs are linked as `/FIXED` so they don't even carry the relocation info required to (re)map them into another app's memory space. Also, in this case the OP doesn't even call LoadLibrary for the EXE explicitly, it gets implicitly loaded as a static dependency of INTERFAC.DLL.

Comment: @dxiv - yes, exe will be loaded, but not relocated(on 0x40000003 code) and import not processed. but however return status must be 0, but from log we view - Status: c000007b - so here else one error

Comment: @dxiv - why you decide that ? i just test this (exe static linked to another exe) - program start with no errors, second exe loaded

Comment: @RbMm You are right, I was misremembering some details. I removed my last comment, and corrected in the posted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One likely explanation for the `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` error from `LoadLibrary` is that `INTERFAC.DLL` was linked with a `PCDLRN.LIB` import library that declares `PCDLRN` exports, but the `PCDLRN.EXE` found at runtime does not have an [exports table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx).

- The `gflags (x86)'s loader snaps` shows that the error is triggered while loading `PCDLRN.EXE`, specifically while resolving the import table of `INTERFAC.DLL`:

  ```
  18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpHandleOneOldFormatImportDescriptor - INFO: DLL "C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL" imports "PCDLRN.exe"
  [...]
  18a0:2a40 @ 06859597 - LdrpHandleOneOldFormatImportDescriptor - ERROR: Loading "?????" from the import table of DLL "C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL" failed with status 0xc000007b
  ```
- Status `0xc000007b` is [STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx):

  > {Bad Image} %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.
- NTSTATUS `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT` is mapped to Win32 error code `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` per [INFO: Mapping NT Status Error Codes to Win32 Error Codes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/113996).

I was able to duplicate the same ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT with a mockup of the given scenario: link `INTERFAC.DLL` to a `PCDLRN.LIB` that declares an exported `foo`, then substitute a `PCDLRN.EXE` without an exports table, and finally attempt to `LoadLibrary` `INTERFAC.DLL`.

As a side note, linking a `DLL` to the import library of another `EXE` is uncommon and fraught with pitfalls. In the case here, even if error 193 is fixed, the functions in the `EXE` would not be directly usable from the `DLL`. See for example [Load EXE as DLL: Mission Possible](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1045674/Load-EXE-as-DLL-Mission-Possible) for more details.

Comment: "export which doesn't exist in the PCDLRN.EXE" - in this case will be error c0000138 or c0000139. really all what need - look under debugger - this task for ˜10 min

Comment: @RbMm Actually it should have been "*no* exports" at all. I just edited that into the answer.

Comment: professional solution - set breakpoint to ZwMapViewOfSection when PCDLRN.EXE maped and then trace. all research take several mins. without binary files hard say in what problem exactly

Comment: yes, you right. if no export table at all - error will be exactly 0xc000007b

Comment: @dxiv In my case, I actually do have an exports table (pcdlrn.exp) in the same directory as the pcdlrn.exe and interfac.dll.

Comment: @markf78 The `.exp` file is an artifact of the MSVC build. The Windows loader is not aware of, or using, any `.exp` files - but rather looks for an export table *inside* the PE image. Try running `dumpbin /exports PCDLRN.EXE` at the cmd prompt configured for your version of MSVC. If it displays a list of `ordinal hint RVA name` entries, then the module (.exe or .dll) has an export table. Otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: @dxiv I added a summary of the dumpbin contents to the question. There are 5784 functions that appear to be exported so i only listed only a couple. Does this look ok?

Comment: @markf78 That indicates the `.exe` has an export table, indeed. This pretty much shoots down my guess, though it's still true that the issue lies with `PCDLRN.EXE` somehow. But there are too many open questions at this point, and asking for a full `dumpbin /all` is not realistic. Maybe you could manage to trim it down to a minimal (and publishable) example.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Though what follows makes sense it is actually incorrect. I'm keeping it here just for reference, but I may delete the answer later.

Note however that (at least on Windows 10, which I used to check) even if relocation information is available in the file, if the module is not a DLL it is not applied, so even if you didn't get that error, unless your INTERFAC.DLL applies relocations to PCLDRN.exe after loading it, trying to use it is likely to break somewhere along the way.

---

With the loader snaps output the situation seems pretty obvious to me.

The loader snaps output once the file is found are (I numbered the lines):

```
(1)  18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpMapViewOfSection - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\PCDLRN.exe
(2)  'CNCServer.exe': Loaded 'C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\PCDLRN.exe', Symbols loaded.
(3)  18a0:2a40 @ 06859597 - LdrpMapViewOfSection - RETURN: Status: 0x40000003
(4)  'CNCServer.exe': Unloaded 'C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\PCDLRN.exe'
(5)  18a0:2a40 @ 06859597 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc000007b
(6)  18a0:2a40 @ 06859597 - LdrpLoadImportModule - ERROR: Loading DLL PCDLRN.exe from path C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:
(7)  18a0:2a40 @ 06859597 - LdrpLoadImportModule - RETURN: Status: 0xc000007b
(8)  18a0:2a40 @ 06859597 - LdrpHandleOneOldFormatImportDescriptor - ERROR: Loading "?????" from the import table of DLL "C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL" failed with status 0xc000007b
(9)  18a0:2a40 @ 06859613 - LdrpUnloadDll - INFO: Unmapping DLL "C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL"
(10) 'CNCServer.exe': Unloaded 'C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.dll'
(11) 18a0:2a40 @ 06859613 - LdrpLoadDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc000007b
(12) 18a0:2a40 @ 06859613 - LdrLoadDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc000007b
```

`LdrpMapViewOfSection` returns an error code (0x40000003) on line 3 which causes the module to unload (line 4) and then `LdrpMapViewOfSection`'s **caller** - `LdrpFindOrMapDll` - translates the error code to 0xc000007b (STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT).

But the error that caused the load to fail was 0x40000003 - `STATUS_IMAGE_NOT_AT_BASE`. The description of this NTSTATUS is:

> {Image Relocated} An image file could not be mapped at the address that is specified in the image file. Local fixes must be performed on this image.

(Source: [NTSTATUS Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx))

By default, EXEs don't contain relocation information (as was mentioned in the comments). Usually that's not a problem as the address space is rather free when the EXE is loaded into it. But your address space isn't free. To make matters worse, all EXEs compiled by Visual C++ share the same base address by default:

> The /BASE option sets a base address for the program, overriding the default location for an .exe or DLL file. The default base address for an .exe file is 0x400000 for 32-bit images or 0x140000000 for 64-bit images. For a DLL, the default base address is 0x10000000 for 32-bit images or 0x180000000 for 64-bit images.

(Source: [Linker Options: /BASE (Base Address)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7f5138s.aspx))

That's probably the situation you have. CNCServer.exe already occupies 0x400000 and that's the only place PCDLRN.exe can go. `LdrpMapViewOfSection` can't map PCDLRN.exe to 0x400000 because it isn't free and fails to map in anywhere else because there's no relocation information.

And from there it goes up the call stack and changes the error, but not the underlying problem. Which is lack of relocation information.

You can see what happened when this error is encountered for a DLL with relocation information in your output too. When INTERFAC.dll is initially loaded:

```
18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL DLL path: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows
    18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpSearchPath - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL DLL path: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\CNCSERVER\Win32\Release;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\s
        18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpResolveFileName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL
        18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpResolveFileName - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
        18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpResolveDllName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL
        18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpResolveDllName - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
    18a0:2a40 @ 06858989 - LdrpSearchPath - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
    18a0:2a40 @ 06859036 - LdrpMapViewOfSection - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL
'CNCServer.exe': Loaded 'C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.dll', Symbols loaded.
    18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpMapViewOfSection - RETURN: Status: 0x40000003
    18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpRelocateImage - ENTER: DLL name: C:\QA\Pcdlrn\Win32\Release\INTERFAC.DLL
        18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpProtectAndRelocateImage - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
    18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpRelocateImage - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
18a0:2a40 @ 06859098 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - RETURN: Status: 0x00000000
```

When `LdrpMapViewOfSection` returns `STATUS_IMAGE_NOT_AT_BASE`, it's caller (`LdrpFindOrMapDll`) goes ahead and calls `LdrpRelocateImage`, something it apparently can't to for PCDLRN.exe.

Comment: Nice catch. Only problem is that I am not able to duplicate the `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` in that case. What I see happening here when the .exe is linked with `/FIXED` (thus without a relocation table) is that the .exe is mapped at a different address, no relocations are performed, but `LoadLibrary` still succeeds. There are other oddities with OP's .exe however (e.g. no `.idata` section) which is why I said that there are too many open questions to second-guess.

Comment: Amazingly true. I tried it too and your right. The EXE is loaded at a different address than it's preferred base without relocations applied. I debugged a bit and found that `ntdll!LdrpMapImage`, after returning from `LdrpMapViewOfSection`, check for the `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` flag, and only if that's the module type it even tries to check whether the NTSTATUS returned from `LdrpMapViewOfSection` was `STATUS_IMAGE_NOT_AT_BASE`. I'll have to try later with a static import etc.

Comment: @conio Yes, I verified that even with the linker option /DYNAMICBASE enabled for pcdlrn.exe the LoadLibrary API function still fails with error code 0xc1.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error 193 until I realised that I was (temporarily) mixing debug and release dlls.